# Configure vsftpd for specsific Cipher Suites and TLS version

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, ssl, vsftpd

There is a device that I do IoT development needs to connect FTP server to download a file.
I'm using vsftpd as an FTP server.

The device that I'm using has some limitations. It supports TLS 1.2 and some chipper suites.
I used the latest version of Ubuntu but I was out of luck to downgrade server TLS 1.2 (I used ubuntu 16.04, which was TLS 1.2)

I'm looking for a way to create an FTP server with TLS 1.2 with the supported chiper suites.

Thanks

**SSL Versions**
SSL3.0, TLS1.2, TLS1.1,TLS1.0

**Supported SSL Cipher Suites**

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

Comment: RC4, SSL 3.0 .. are insecure and long considered obsolete. That's why they are no longer supported by default in modern TLS stacks, i.e. usually not even compiled into shipped versions of OpenSSL which means there is also no way to enable these. You would need to use some fairly old software stack to support these ciphers. At the same time though you like to have modern ciphers which are not available in such older TLS stacks. I think you need to compile your own version of modern openssl but with older ciphers enabled to achieve this. Then compile the FTP server against this.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The list of cipher suites you posted includes some modern cipher suites. You don't need any special backward compatibility or downgrade. It looks like Ubuntu ships vsftpd with SSL disabled it by default, have you enabled it? What cipher suites have you enabled? What happens when the device tries to connect?

Comment: I asked a different question on `ask ubuntu` to downgrade server from TLS 1.3 to TLS 1.2 and I noticed the chiper suit might be problematic. I have some screens shot in there. [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371967/downgrade-to-tls-1-2-on-20-04-1-ubuntu-in-vsftpd)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I enabled SSL and the device hangs while connecting to the FTP server (no response from server). I don't know how to enable or disable chiper suits so I leave as is.

Comment: TLS servers can, and usually do, support multiple protocol versions. In 2021, you're unlikely to encounter a TLS server that doesn't support TLS 1.2. Post your vsftpd configuration (`/etc/vsftpd.conf`).